# 2-dimensional invariant subspace of $T_a$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ a \in \mathbb{R} $, and $ T_a: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ be given by:
$$ T_a \left( \; \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ x \end{bmatrix} \; \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 4x-z \\ (6-3a)x + ay + (3a-6)z \\ 2x + z \end{bmatrix} $$
Find two values of $a$ such that there is a 2-dimensional invariant subspace of $ T_a $

*Finding a matrix associated with this transformation is fine, and so is finding all the eigenstuff, but what can I do with this information to find values of* a *that yield an invariant subspace?*